# React Native/Android - Can not find dependencies using + sign

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working with a react native app that is using many packages. Since upgrading React Native to 0.58 the build process crashes on Android with error: cannot find symbol.

I found the problem to be that many of the 3:rd part packages (e.g react-native-svg) have a statement like this in their build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```

It works if I change to + to be the specific React Native version I'm using:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.0'
}
```

This is not manageable though since these files are in node_modules which is .gitignore:d. That means I have to change all these gradle files every time I do npm install for example. Why isn't it working when using a + in 'implementation'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to change the dependencies of all versions.

```
sed -i -- "s/com\.facebook\.react:react-native:+/com\.facebook\.react:react-native:0.58.0/" node_modules/**/android/build.gradle
sed -i -- "s/com\.facebook\.react:react-native:+/com\.facebook\.react:react-native:0.58.0/" node_modules/**/android/app/build.gradle
sed -i -- "s/com\.facebook\.react:react-native:+/com\.facebook\.react:react-native:0.58.0/" android/app/build.gradle
```

The non-functioning point of using + in 'Execute' appears to be that the .gradle on Android has not been modified, or the module is referring to an older version of the node module file.